# Need help opening an exe in c++ with cmd

Tags: c++, batch-file

```cpp
std::cout << "starting valorant...";
            system("d:");
            system("cd" "Riot Games\\VALORANT\\live\\");
            system("VALORANT.exe");
```

I need help opening an `.exe` with `cmd` (Valorant, in this case).

Results:

[image]

Comment: Each `system` function call runs its own shell. The three `system` calls you make are totally independent of each other. Create a single BAT file that does what you want, and invoke that instead.

Comment: If you use Visual C++ for compilation of your C++ code, then the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) should be used which is used also by `cmd.exe` to run any executable specified on command line or in a batch file. That would make it possible to start `D:\Riot Games\VALORANT\live\VALORANT.exe` directly with its full qualified file name and your code defines the current working directory for this executable and if it should be run as separate process detached from your exe.

Comment: Also note that `"cd" "Riot Games\\VALORANT\\live\\"` will concatenate the string *without* a space between them, it's the same as `"cdRiot Games\\VALORANT\\live\\"` which is one of the things the text in the image complains about. Also never show images of text, copy-paste text as text.

Answer (score 2):

Each call to `system()` spawns a new instance of the shell processor (`cmd.exe /c <parameters>` on Windows). You can't use multiple calls to `system()` to issue multiple commands to a single shell instance, the way you are trying to do.

You should instead be using a single call to `system()` with the full path the `.exe`, eg:

```cpp
std::cout << "starting valorant...";
system("\"d:\\Riot Games\\VALORANT\\live\\VALORANT.exe\"");
```

Alternatively, use an old DOS 8.3-style path (if enabled - use `GetShortPathName()` to get the actual path):

```cpp
std::cout << "starting valorant...";
system("d:\\RiotGa~1\\VALORANT\\live\\VALORANT.exe");
```

Otherwise, you should use `CreateProcess()` instead of `system()`:

```cpp
std::cout << "starting valorant...";

STARTUPINFO si = {}
si.cb = sizeof(si);
// set other fields as needed...

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

if (CreateProcessA(NULL, "d:\\Riot Games\\VALORANT\\live\\VALORANT.exe", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    // use pi as needed...
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still have error. I think the space between 'Riot' and 'Games' is the issue, but I can't really find a fix. Tried like 'Riot_Games', but not working.

starting valorant...'d:\Riot' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @ProgrammerWannabe try `"\"d:\\Riot Games\\VALORANT\\live\\VALORANT.exe\""`. `system` simulates a command prompt; if you wanted to run it from a command prompt you'd have to put quote marks "" around the command because of the space.

Comment: @user253751 I tried that out, I think that will work, but now I am getting "access denied." :/ edit: even with admin privileges.

Comment: @ProgrammerWannabe update what you tried to the question. And you should use raw string literal instead for better readability: `R"(d:\Riot Games\VALORANT\live\VALORANT.exe)"`